# How to use Views on custom route?

Tags: views, 8, routes

Views require "Use AJAX" in order to display exposed filters when using Block display. I think this is necessary to avoid submitting/influencing other form elements on the current page.

I have a page that is a View but my page has to have a certain route name because my app relies on it. So I've used Block display for the Views instead of the Page display.

But I want the user to see the filtering arguments in URL so he can save the search or link to it. So obviously I will have to use the Page display for my view. But how can I use the Views with mine route?

---

Is is a good idea to create a Page view with some dummy path and load the View's route and get it's content and display it via mine route controller?

---

At first I've used the config option mentioned by Daniel Wehner but I ended up with using a custom filtering form + query tag. This gave me much better flexibility and customization options than Views' exposed filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can try out:

1. Write a display plugin for views which extends the  page one and allows you to specficy the route name in the UI. Note: views already uses a option in the view yml file 'route_name' if it is available:

   ```
   display:
    page_1:
      display_options:
        path: node
        route_name: hallo_world
   ```

   So you could just hack your yml file and be done.
2. Use the route alter event and simply rename the route generated by views:

   ```
   protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
     if ($route = $collection->get("view.$view_id.$display_id")) {
       $collection->remove("view.$view_id.$display_id"); // not sure about the method name.
       $collection->add('hey.this.is.my.cystom.route.name', $route);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Be okay with the name views generates, as it won't change over time.

Comment: No idea but I don't get the code to look like code, anyone with an idea how to do it?

Comment: [This](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2524/block-code-in-lists-possible) post explains how to make code work in lists. Essentially just more indention...

Comment: I've used the #1 approach and works like a charm. I get why this is hidden from the UI but this really needs to be mentioned in the documentation later on when 8.0 will be out.

Comment: I will not fight that but some people just have a different thoughts about enpowering people than I do have